# The Mystery behind auto update of some Environment in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can change my custom Environment called **backgroundColor** in View Level so easily with an environment modifier! Like this down code:

```
CustomView()
  .environment(\.backgroundColor, toggleCustomViewBackgroundColor ? Color.yellow : Color.green)
```

As you can see I can change/update `@Environment(\.backgroundColor) var backgroundColor: Color` for **CustomView()**. And it works fine!

So how could I change/update `@Environment(\.backgroundColor) var backgroundColor: Color` in entire of Project?

Maybe some of you would say do this:

```
ContentView()
  .environment(\.backgroundColor, toggleAppBackgroundColor ? Color.yellow : Color.green)
```

And it would be a way for updating `@Environment(\.backgroundColor) var backgroundColor: Color` in entire of Project, but as we now **colorScheme** does **NOT** work in that way! It updates itself in entire of Project without using environment modifier depending on current actual dark/light mode of Device!

**So let me say what happened!** colorScheme can update itself without using ***environment modifier*** of course it has a logic that makes that update happen in entire of Project, For making all thing easy for us I made a Button that it plays a roll of a logic that would update `@Environment(\.backgroundColor) var backgroundColor: Color` in entire of Project without using environment modifier, So **how** **colorScheme** can update itself, I want make that functionality for my **Custom-Environment** as well. For example with tapping on that Button **backgroundColor-Environment** would understand that now it is time to updating **backgroundColor** in entire of Project. Which every child View would notice to new update! like **colorScheme**.

---

```
private struct BackgroundColorKey: EnvironmentKey {
    
    static var defaultValue = Color.yellow
    
}


extension EnvironmentValues {
    
    var backgroundColor: Color {
        get { return self[BackgroundColorKey.self] }
        set(newValue) { self[BackgroundColorKey.self] = newValue }
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.backgroundColor) var backgroundColor: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Hello world!")
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .padding()
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.backgroundColor) var backgroundColor: Color
    
    @State private var toggleCustomViewBackgroundColor: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        Button("Update backgroundColor in App Level!") {
            
            // Update backgroundColor in App Level, witout using environment modifier!!!
        }
        .padding()
        
        
        Text("Hello world!")
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .padding()
        
        
        Button("toggle backgroundColor in View Level!") {
            
            toggleCustomViewBackgroundColor.toggle()
        }
        .padding()
        
        CustomView()
            .environment(\.backgroundColor, toggleCustomViewBackgroundColor ? Color.yellow : Color.green)
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know my question was searching for an answer to updating ***a custom Environment*** without using ***environment modifier*** like **colorScheme** for example.

This is what i think should be happened with **ColorScheme Environment** for example! Apple did something like this down code by default for our every single SwiftUI projects we create! but that ***environment modifier*** applied **Undercover!** *we are not able to see it!* I have prove for that!

```
ContentView()
  .environment(\.colorScheme, colorSchemeUpdater())
```

**The prove of my theory:**

If you try read **colorScheme** in **App** it would not update itself for actual right value! because in App ***environment modifier*** for **colorScheme** did not applied to get new update! try this down code for yourself now! It would not show or update the true value of **colorScheme**!

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct EnvironmentApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            Text(colorScheme == .dark ? "dark" : "light")
            
            ContentView()     
        }
    }
}
```

But If you try this down code it would working and it will show right value! Even we did not explicitly used ***environment modifier*** for **colorScheme** on **ContentView()** because Apple done it for us **Undercover!**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        
        Text(colorScheme == .dark ? "dark" : "light")
    }
    
}
```

---

The other environments have the same thing like **scenePhase, horizontalSizeClass, verticalSizeClass**, all got applied by default to Views in side **WindowGroup**

---

**Mystery Solved!**

---